# How to Customize a Report in Micros 3700

Tags: point-of-sale

My daughter is trying to do a good turn for her restaurant. They have a nice report in Micros 3700 telling them how many chickens they consume per day, but they need it to tell them how many chickens they consume per hour. Management says it's impossible to customize the reports, and I know that's not right. What I don't know is whether it's so hard as to be practically impossible.

Anyone with insight? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Micros 3700 Systems us a Sybase Database (or Microsoft SQL Server - this seems to be less common)  -  There is documentation located within the installation that describes the format and configuration of the database.  Information is strangely sparse on the internet.

The schema changes throughout versions, so make sure you find documentation for the version installed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set up the hourly time periods.  Then you can run a menu item by time report filtered by a block of time, and range of items.

Answer (score 2):

Those reports are produced using Crystal Reports.  You can contact your local micros district and pay for customized reports.  Why dont you just look at the other available reports in the Autosequence Module on the micros server.

Answer (score -1):

you should go to "my micros" in there you can find anything ran through the registers. You can even search by category, for example we had a special one day and I had to find out how many specials we went through and I found out that we went through 180 in one day. hope that helps. "my micros" will be in your windows search bar not in any micros reports.